# dplyr rename error: contains unknown variables

Tags: r, dplyr

Very simple, renaming colnames with dplyr gives me an odd error.

```
 library(dplyr)

 df <- data.frame(var1=c("one","two","three"),var2=c(1,2,3)) 

 df <- 
    df %>% 
    rename(var1=are.letters, var2=are.numbers)

Error: `are.letters`, `are.numbers` contains unknown variables
```

second try

```
 df <- rename(df, var1=are.letters, var2=are.numbers)

Error: `are.letters`, `are.numbers` contains unknown variables
```

Wondering if quoting....

```
df <- 
    df %>% 
    rename('var1'='are.letters', 'var2'='are.numbers')

Error: `are.letters`, `are.numbers` contains unknown variables
```

Comment: If you want to name the column names with 'are.eltters' and 'are.numbers, it should be the other way. Did you meant `df %>% rename(are.letters = var1, are.numbers = var2)`

Comment: @Akrun you're right. The order is just the opposite. Counter-intuitive IMHO

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Just made the same error.  So, I'm converting @akrun's useful comment into an "answer."

To fix this, the new name should be on the left hand of the equal sign and the existing name should be on the right.

Like this:

```
df <- df %>% 
    rename(are.letters = var1, are.numbers = var2)
```